# Is a SQL Server recursive CTE considered a loop?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I was under the impression that recursive CTEs were set based, but in a [recent SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824831/generate-dates-between-date-ranges/7824919#comment9537416_7824919) someone mentioned that they are loops.

Are recursive CTEs set based?  Am I wrong to assume that a set based operation cannot be a loop?

Comment: [Related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803640/how-cte-really-works/7807483#7807483)

Comment: +1 as it is still an excellent question.

Comment: Declarative vs procedural might be a more useful and meaningful distinction to make?

Answer (score 2):

If it is recursive it is still considered a loop.
Although one statement is set based, calling it over and over can be considered a loop.  This is an argument about the definition or wording based on the context being used.  They are set based statements but the processing is considered in simple terms a looping process.

For those interested here is a nice little write up about performance with CTE's:

http://explainextended.com/2009/11/18/sql-server-are-the-recursive-ctes-really-set-based/

Answer (score 2):

They are set based. Recursive sets are still sets.

But all set operations are, if you look with a powerful enough magnifier glass, loops. Ultimately the code runs on CPUs and CPUs execute a stream of serial instructions that operate on discrete regions of memory. In other words, there is no *set oriented hardware*. Being 'set oriented' is a logical concept. The fact that *all* SQL operations are ultimately implemented using some form of a loop is an implementation detail.

Comment: Indeed, even Itzik Ben Gan's undoubtedly [set based numbers table generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers/2663232#2663232) is still implemented as a bunch of nested loops in the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

I think the distinction that needs to be done is "tail recursion" versus "general recursion".

All tail recursions can be implemented as loops - without the need for a Stack.

General recursion support can also be implemented as a Loop - but with a stack.

Recursive CTEs are Tail recursions and hence essentially a Loop. The only difference is the terminating condition is handled by SQL semantics/execution engine. The output from each Loop iteration is UNIONed or whatever set op you specify.